# How to collect Symfony cache metrics in production?

Tags: symfony, shopware6, symfony5.4

I am using Symfony 5.4 together with Shopware 6.4

I would like to collect metrics about the cache usage like hits/misses in production.
This should be done in a way that doesnt impact production performance, of course.

Is there a way to do this without implementing custom code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony and/or Shopware do not provide out of the box features for collecting cache metrics like hits and misses. I think you need to look at a library that can do this for you or implement custom code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to receive similar information regarding database cache performance on the database itself, such as using MySQL Workbench for SQL databases, etc, In there you can see things like cache performance.

Within Symfony, the Profiler component will provide this information to you in Dev Mode. It should never be run in production for many reason, not the least is security and performance. The overall cache performance between your dev and prod environments should be very similar, in that, when running through the same steps, you should see the same cache hit to miss ratio. There is no real reason why dev should behave differently than production with the exception of cache expiration.